# Redirect draft/preview URL to permalink AFTER post is published

Tags: wordpress, url, redirect, permalinks, preview

I've experienced a problem several times where a draft/preview URL for a post is being widely circulated by accident, and I am unable to edit/correct the link (ex. sent in an email newsletter) to the permalink. When someone tries to visit the draft/preview URL, they are not able to access the post, even after it has been published and made public.

Are there solutions that would take anyone trying to access a post using a draft/preview URL and redirect them to the public permalink URL for the post IF said post has been published?

I'd really appreciate any ideas from the community.

Answer (score 1):

> You need to submit the reference code for better help.

Anyway, if you have or can get the post id than you may try redirect using [get_post_status()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_status/) function.

```
<?php

    // get the post id from your draft/preview url
    global $post;
    $id = $post->ID;

    // check if the post for the id is published
    if ( 'publish' == get_post_status( $id )) {
        wp_redirect(get_permalink($id));
        exit;
    }

?>
```